# Numeric String Formatting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

C# has the very useful ability to format numeric values with a format string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

From what I have read it appears JavaScript has no such functionality. Is anyone aware of a library that will do something similar or is it a case of having to create your own code? Maybe I am mistaken and there is inbuilt support for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [jQuery pluggin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter) to achieve the similar functionality in javascript.

Also [here](http://ntt.cc/2008/04/25/6-very-basic-but-very-useful-javascript-number-format-functions-for-web-developers.html) you can find customized javascript functions which would help you for number formatting.

There are some javascript functions like `toPrecision` and `toFixed` which can be used for basic formatting.

Comment: Thanks looks to be useful! Cheers! I'll spend some time investigating it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support for string formatting in JavaScript, but how about the [sprintf port for JavaScript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf)?